# Resultset returns String with unicode

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, oracle11g

In the database I see the value in the column and it contains 
`á`

but when I do a Resultset.getString, the printed String comes out as
`\303\241`

I'm not sure what's happening exactly as the Database is in UTF-8 and it seems to be displaying the correct value when I look in SQLDeveloper.

Comment: Please add the code block where you get the resultSet

Answer (score 0):

this is database character set encoding problem, you need to check it out the database character set and change it.